# How to bind scope parameters to url using service

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to bind the scope variables to the get service in controller.

```
My service file
app.service('loginService', function ($http) {

    var Service = {};
    Service.getLogin = function () {

        return $http.get('http://183.8/HMS/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/');

    };

    return Service;

})
```

and in my controller i have to use above service like below by passing email id and password

```
loginService.getLogin( + $scope.emailId + '/' + $scope.password);
```

without service  i am able to get the solution but with service this two parameters are not binding to URL,Any solution please help.

Comment: where do you handle + $scope.emailId + '/' + $scope.password in your service

Comment: @RohanPawar the complete url given by API  Team is  http://183.82/HMS/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/{EMAILID}/{PASSWORD}

Comment: you need to bind parameter to url

Comment: @RohanPawar I am new to angular and i dont know how to bind this parameters please help.

Comment: checkout my answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service function should return the new Object, something like this

```
  var Service = function(){
           this.getLogin = function (email,password) {
                return $http.get('http://183.8/HMS/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/'+email+'/'+password);

            };
     }       
    return new Service();
```

and call your service like this

```
loginService.getLogin( $scope.emailId , $scope.password);
```

or change the service function to factory

```
app.factory('loginService', function ($http) {
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but they are not binding to url

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
app.service('loginService', function ($http) {

        function getLoginCall(url) {
            return $http.get('http://183.8/HMS/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/'+url);
        }

        return {
            getLogin:getLoginCall
        };

    });
```

and in your contorller

```
loginService.getLogin($scope.emailId + '/' + $scope.password);
```